# Synology - `du -sh .` takes forever on the NAS but no time when mounted on Mac

Tags: mount, performance, macos, nas, synology

My NAS has seemed slow and I'm not sure what tests to run to prove this.  But this example I'm about to describe has happened and something has really gone bad. I'm hoping for answers for what I need to do to fix this and / or any troubleshooting I can perform.

I mounted a NAS share on my Mac using connect to server - `mount` tells me its SMB:

```
//ben@home-nas.local/ben on /Volumes/ben-1 (smbfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by bbos)
```

I copied local data to it.  After it was finished I wanted to confirm that the copy to the mount happened so I ran `du -sk .` on the local mount and the same thing after `ssh`ing to the NAS and changing to the same directory.

The local `du` took maybe 15 seconds.  The one on the NAS is still running 5 mins later (it finished after about 10min - the answer for local was 395GB and 390GB on the NAS - I think the difference would just be due to blocksize - but i may be wrong and happy to be corrected here).

The NAS is a Synology DS1515+ with 5 x 6TB drives, RAID-6. It has 6GB of RAM and is always running the latest DSM, which is currently DSM 6.2.2-24922 Update 4. I run a couple extra services but nothing wild. For most of this 5 mins the CPU usage has been ~ 12% and RAM ~ 26%.

I don't have a good enough understanding to know what is going on and hoping for some advice and answers to some questions.

If I'm running a `du` on my Mac then doesn't that mean the file system on the NAS is sending data across the network (both are connected to the same router with gigabit ethernet). Doesn't this imply that it is NOT the NAS hardware, nor the DSM OS but must be the `du` command that is the issue?

But that doesn't make any sense.  I'm missing something.  Has anyone any thoughts on what might be causing this? What I can do to troubleshoot this further and what I might be able to do to solve it?

When I say "seemed slow" at the top, the NAS sometimes seems to be unresponsive.  I've never thought much of it, just that the disks need to spin up though every-now-and-then it can take 10+ seconds or so and just seems a bit odd.  Now I've seen this other problem I will consider these issues more closely.  Again, any advice appreciated!

Comment: No responses, i thought Synology would monitor this.  I will post over on their forums.

Answer (score 0):

You have Synology DS1515+ with 5 x 6TB drives, RAID-6? I would redo everything with RAID 10 Or use Synology Hybrid RAID and have either configuration with btrfs. I have found that it works better (faster) with that setup concerning data transfer. Try that and go from there.

As far as networking it defaults to tcp/ip. SMB is ok but again you can transfer files either way using the protocols. Since you're using MAC try adding the apple protocol also. You can always change it.

Comment: Hi Jagosix, thanks though that doesn't answer my question.  BTW it wasn't me that downvoted you.

Comment: Hello. I'm not worried about the down votes. I'm just trying to help the best way I can. Also try disabling the SMB and using IP only and see if that will change anything.